# PHP cURL starts giving error 100

Tags: php, curl

I have build an generic method in php for handling all my requests against an API. I do however have a problem which I can't seem to understand. After I've done a couple of requests against the API, and wait for about 3 minutes curl starts giving error code 100. And it continues until I have restarted the API Service (Build on Grizzly, Java).

Is there any curl configuration in my method which may be incorrect?

Thanks for any help
The method look like this:

```
/**
 * This function will handle all server requests
 * @param $RequestPath String This variable decide which endpoint will be called on
 * @param $Method String GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
 * @param $DataArray Array Data that will be sent to the server
 * @param $SessionKey String SessionKey is received if the user have a logged in session.
 * @return Array Will send back array based on the JSON response from server
 */
public static function SendRequest($RequestPath, $Method, $DataArray, $SessionKey = null){

    /* Import configurations */
    $configRest_Security = Config::Security();

    /* Build the request URL */
    $url = "https://localhost:6010/".$RequestPath;

    /* Assign the public Key */
    $PublicKey = $configRest_Security["PublicKeyPKCS8"];

    /* Encode every array value and add them to the url path */
    foreach($DataArray as $value){
        $url = $url."/".rawurlencode(stripcslashes($value));
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    /* Set URI for the request */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    /* Set the method of this request */
    if($Method == "POST"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    }elseif($Method == "PUT"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    }elseif($Method == "DELETE"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $Method);
    }elseif($Method == "OPTIONS"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $Method);
    }

    /* If SessionKey was set, send it with the request */
    if(!empty($SessionKey)){
        $Authentication = "Basic ".Cipher::Encrypt($SessionKey.":".(time()+5));
    }else{
        $Authentication = "None";
    }

    /* Create a HTTP Header */
    $header = array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Accept-Charset: utf-8",
        "Content-Length: 0",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-PublicKey: ".$PublicKey,
        "Authorization: ".$Authentication,
    );

    /* Set HTTP Header in cURL */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    /* Set Timeout */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    /* Fetch Answer */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    /* Don't check self signed certificate */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  FALSE);

    /* Execute curl command */
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpReturnCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($httpReturnCode != 200){
        echo "HTTP Error: ".$httpReturnCode;
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Comment: Check if your REST request is not missing any arguments. Code 100 generally stands for not supplying all arguments.

Comment: Found my issue, had database connections on the server which didn't close properly, and then made the server hang when it had several requests..